# Parsing a KML file

Tags: java, kml

How can I parse a KML file using Java such that all the attributes and sub attributes can be easily extracted?
It would be highly helpful if any code snippets are shared.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Java API for KML](https://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak.html) (JAK) is probably the simplest Java API to parse KML files.

Here is a snippet of Java code to extract the coordinates from a KML file.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Kml.class);

// create KML reader to parse arbitrary KML into Java Object structure
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Kml kml = (Kml) u.unmarshal(new File("test.kml"));

Placemark placemark = (Placemark) kml.getFeature();
Polygon geom = (Polygon) placemark.getGeometry();
LinearRing linearRing = geom.getOuterBoundaryIs().getLinearRing();
List<Coordinate> coordinates = linearRing.getCoordinates();
for (Coordinate coordinate : coordinates) {
    System.out.println(coordinate.getLongitude());
    System.out.println(coordinate.getLatitude());
    System.out.println(coordinate.getAltitude());
}
```

There are code examples and tutorials on the JAK website.
https://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak.html